# Does the method of adjustment matter, or just the final calibration?

Tags: software, automation, release

A company produces software (and hardware) that is used to both perform automatic *adjustments* on electronic test equipment as well as perform *calibrations* of the same equipment. The results of the calibrations are put onto a certificate of calibration that is sent to the customer along with the equipment.

This calibration certificate states various conditions of the calibration, such as what hardware (models/serial numbers) and software (version) was used to perform the calibration, as well as things like environmental conditions, etc.

Making the assumption that the software used to produce the data (and listed on the calibration certificate) used on the certificate of calibration must have gone through a "test/release" process and must be considered "released" software - does this also mean that the software used for adjustment must also be released?

I believe that the method (software/environmental conditions/etc) used or present during adjustment doesn't matter, all that really matters is the end result of the calibration, the conditions *present during the calibration*, and whether or not the equipment was within the specifications.

The real question I'm hoping to get answered: *Is there a reputable source (e.g. NIST or somewhere similar) that addresses this question?* (I have searched...)

The thinking is that during high volume production runs, the "unreleased" system can be used to perform adjustments, as long as a released system is used to perform the calibrations, since the time required to perform the adjustments is much longer than the calibration. This unreleased system will eventually become released for use, but currently is not.

Also, please not that there is a distinction between "adjustment" and "calibration". The definition from [BIPM International vocabulary of metrology](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_200_2008.pdf), 2.39:

> Operation that, under specified conditions, in a first step,
>   establishes a relation between the quantity values with measurement
>   uncertainties provided by measurement standards and corresponding
>   indications with associated measurement uncertainties (of the
>   calibrated instrument or secondary standard) and, in a second step,
>   uses this information to establish a relation for obtaining a
>   measurement result from an indication.

Followed by NOTE 2 (emphasis in original text):

> Calibration should not be confused with **adjustment of a measuring
>   system**, often mistakenly called "self-calibration", nor with
>   **verification** of calibration

As a side note, I'm not sure why this got down voted. It's regarding software and it's use before and after release for use. I believe there is a best practice that can be applied and this is (hopefully) not primarily opinion based.

Comment: If your question is merely "where can I find a NIST source," then it is off-topic here.  We're not a search engine.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that I could not find an answer to this specific question utilizing search engines, or sites like NIST or A2LA.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, this is a software site.  Nobody here is going to tell you to rely on unproven software for a critical operation.  Just sayin'; you don't need OSHA or NIST to tell you that.

Comment: Yes, but do you ever write a utility to automate generating, let's say, a lookup table for trig functions? The numbers in the table matter, not really the implementation of the `sin()` function used. And that utility doesn't always go through V&V and acceptance testing beyond your own unit testing, right?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I never rely solely on my own testing, if the software is going to be relied upon for anything other than my own curiosity.  I wrote the software, after all; I *already know it works.* :)

Comment: To be clearer, where I work, software goes through a characterization process to identify the level of rigor required of the testing process.  Utilities have lower requirements for testing than real-time production components do.  But *everything* gets a secondary test, even if it's just a buddy check.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are leaning solely on the results of equipment calibrations to serve as [Verification and Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verification_and_validation) for a piece of unreleased software.

If the *only* requirement in the software design specification for the unreleased software is that it must be capable of making adjustments to a piece of equipment under calibration, then that may be a valid approach.  *But seldom does software have only a single such requirement.*  If there are other software requirements, then I would say that this approach is not valid.

It is these kinds of rationalizations that eventually lead to problems like the Ariane 5 explosion, or the Therac-25 accidents, or sudden acceleration in Toyota vehicles.

Comment: The thinking is that during high volume production runs, the "unreleased" system can be used to perform adjustments, as long as a released system is used to perform the calibrations, since the time required to perform the adjustments is much longer than the calibration.

Comment: Whether you can get away with it or not does depend in large part on the nature of the equipment being calibrated.  If it is ordinary VOM's, there might not be a problem at all.  If it involves the calibration of durable medical equipment or equipment that could cause loss of life or injury if it fails, you might run afoul of laws or government regulations.

Comment: That's similar to an example I used - if we're calibrating a meter stick against a standard, does it really matter if a saw or a laser was used to trim the length of the meter stick? All that really matters is how long the resulting stick is.

Comment: Ah, but both the saw and the laser went through a QA process.

Comment: The saw didn't necessarily need to go through a QA process. I could have simply broke the stick to the right length - did my hand/arm system need to go through a QA process? Also - the example given isn't to accomplish verification or validation, but to temporarily support a production process.

Comment: I consider breaking the stick a straw man; you calibrate a piece of equipment by hand because it is *designed to be calibrated that way.*  You use a saw or a laser for cutting the stick because that's what they are designed to do.  If you can do it with a script, and the equipment is designed to be calibrated with user-written scripts, then I'd say you're probably in the clear.  Do you see the line I'm drawing?  It's not a line you can step over cavalierly.

Comment: *"Designed to be calibrated that way"* - Do you really mean calibrated, or adjusted? There is a distinction there.

Comment: Adjustment is part of the calibration process.

Comment: Calibration is "Operation that, under specified conditions, in a first step, establishes a relation between the quantity values with measurement uncertainties provided by measurement standards and corresponding indications with associated measurement uncertainties (of the calibrated instrument or secondary standard) and, in a second step, uses this information to establish a relation for obtaining a measurement result from an indication." That does not include adjustment.

Comment: Are you really claiming that you can calibrate a piece of equipment without adjusting it in some way if it's calibration is off? :)  We can talk legalisms all day long, but at the end of the day, your company has to decide for itself if it's a safe and valid procedure.  In my experience, the adjustment process during a calibration is very specific; I'd sleep better at night if the software I wrote to do that was verified and validated that it fulfilled the specificity of that adjustment process.

Comment: Absolutely you can. Standards laboratories all over the world trade standards between themselves, and perform calibrations without adjustments all the time. This is especially true if you're interested in the long term stability of something like a reference or transfer standard. You don't necessarily want to have a piece of equipment measure with zero error (in fact, that's not really even possibly), but you want to know *how far off from nominal* it is.

Comment: OK.  But if you don't need to adjust it, then you don't need unproven software to make the adjustments for you, do you?

Comment: This is the same problem I'm in that prompted this question - can you point me to documentation that addresses this specific question? I have a group of people where some think one way and some another, and it would be great to point to some documentation from a reputable source that addresses this very topic. This conversation in comments, and your answer, don't address my question except with what I believe is an opinion (which means if there is no documentation, this question is off-topic anyway! :)

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question by adding a bit more detail about the nature of the adjustment which is being automated.  How is the adjustment accomplished manually?  How is it being automated by your software?  What's the substantive difference?

Answer (score 1):

Adjustment is the process of re calibration. Calibration is the state of the systems accuracy and errors. From a regulatory framework, it is rare to worry how the adjustment was done, and common to worry about the calibration. Hence the need for calibration certificates. (It is common to worry that adjustment cannot be done after calibration, I will ignore that for now....)

A simple example might be the calibration of a fuel pump at your local service station. You care that is is calibrated correctly, as does the law. Typically its done by filling  test bucket, but maybe its done putting a flow meter on the pump nozzle while filling a car. In both cases, the test equipment must also be calibrated (usually to a higher standard).  However, if the pump is reading wrong and needs adjustment, it does not matter if this is done by a setting in software, turning a trim pot or replacing a sensor.

In a production environment it is not normally required (within a regulatory framework) that the adjustment process be rigorous, i.e. you can use whatever means you want in production to adjust, including unreleased automated software, provided the system is calibrated to the regulatory/commercial requirements. However, in my experience, the commercial risk and cost of unreleased software in high volume production lines means it just does not happen, as therefore the two tasks are often performed by the same system.

Note: Some frameworks with strict control (life critical systems etc) will have regulatory oversight of adjustment and calibration. In this case the answer does not stand.

Comment: `if the pump is reading wrong and needs adjustment, it does not matter if this is done by a setting in software, turning a trim pot or replacing a sensor.` -- I think it goes a little deeper than that.  The question is not about the mechanism of adjustment; it's about whether that mechanism can be automated safely with non-certified software.

Comment: @Robert is correct. Calibration is measuring how close the adjustments came to "true". How the adjustments got there might not matter. This second statement is the crux of the matter.

Comment: Tx answer edited.